# Javascript scrolling issues in Edge/Opera/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a CSGO style box opening for my food recipe site, for when you want a random recipe.
But i am encountering a couple issues with the scrolling. It has a couple browser compatibility issues, it does not work at all in Edge, Opera, and Chrome, only Firefox handles it without issues.

I made a small codepen with the relevant code here: https://codepen.io/jlmadsen/pen/GRWKLKv

But i suspect this code block is the culprit.

```js
let total_length = image_container.scrollWidth - (450*2.5)
image_container.scrollTo(0,0)

scroll_interval = setInterval(() => {
  let remaining = total_length - image_container.scrollLeft
  
  // if further than 30 units away keep scrolling
  if (remaining > 30) {
    let distance = remaining / 15
    image_container.scrollTo(image_container.scrollLeft + distance, 0);
  } else {
    // stop scroling
  }
}, 15 );
```

Hope someone can help me with the browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your interval is too short. The browser does not have time to "accelerate" the scroll.

Also perhaps `scrollBy()` would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Increasing the interval makes the scrolling stutter. Just changing to `scollBy()` did not work either, but it may work if there is a way to slow down the scrolling?